# How do I debug git error: "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout" when there's nothing to stash?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm using git-svn, and I'm trying to run `git svn rebase`.

I get the error:

```
Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
<filename>
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
```

I have previously run `git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>`, and made changes to the file, but I've now run `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <filename>` to get rid of that.

`git status` doesn't report any changes and `git stash` says there's nothing to stash.

I have checked that the file is not in `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude`

How can I debug this problem further?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that I had the `skip-worktree` bit set, so I needed to run

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree <filename>
```

I found this out by running

```
git ls-files -v | grep "^[^H]"
```

(Or `git ls-files -v | where { $_ -match "^[^H]"}` with Windows Powershell)

Typing `git help ls-files` explained what the output meant.

Answer (score 12):

I was having this problem and Tim's answer helped me figure out the solution.

In the past I had run:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged index.php
```

## The Problem

After making a bunch of changes to another branch remotely, I was getting the overwrite warning while trying to switch over locally.

```
git checkout other-branch

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
index.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Stashing wasn't working.

```
git stash save --keep-index
No local changes to save
```

## The Solution

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged index.php
git add index.php
git commit
```

After that.

```
git checkout other-branch
```

Success!

Comment: Thanks for your post. In my case something similar happened whereby I modified the file, then I did the git update --assume-unchanged that resulted in this error. I had to follow your solution by doing the --no-assume-unchanged, commit, and then thereafter --assume-unchanged. Only push thereafter

Comment: If you use `git commit`, all your local changes in index.php will go to remote, and everybody, who will pull the project, will get your changes, isn't it? git proposes 2 ways in this error case: commit or stash. So, I prefer use `git stash` after `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged`.